# Fill the tableview with data from database

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a tableview in javafx and i want it to display all my data coming from the database in the tableview but when i run the program it only display 1 row with info instead of 6 rows with the information that i needed here is my code

```
    idTextField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) 
        {   
            if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
            {
                try 
                {
                    // Get a result set containing all data from test_table

                    PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM abrasaldo where grade_No = ?");

                    // For each row of the result set ...

                    int getData = Integer.parseInt(idTextField.getText());

                    st.setInt(1 , getData);

                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

                    if (rs.next()) 
                    {

                        ObservableList<StudentClass> datatable = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


                        for(int i = 1; 1 < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
                        {

                            datatable.add(new StudentClass(rs.getInt("grade_No") , rs.getString("grade_Code"), 
                                    rs.getString("grade_Title"), rs.getString("grade_SubjectDesc"),
                                    rs.getDouble("grade_Grade"), rs.getString("grade_DaySched"),
                                    rs.getString("grade_TimeSched"), rs.getString("grade_Room"), 
                                    rs.getString("grade_Term"), rs.getDouble("grade_Unit"), rs.getString("grade_Faculty")));
                        }

                        table.setItems(datatable);  
                        noDataLabel.setText("");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ObservableList<StudentClass> datatable = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                        table.setItems(datatable);

                        noDataLabel.setText("No Data");
                        noDataLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                    }
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) 
                {
                    ObservableList<StudentClass> datatable = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                    table.setItems(datatable);

                    noDataLabel.setText("No Data");
                    noDataLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                }
                catch (SQLException e) 
                {
                    noDataLabel.setText("No Data");
                    noDataLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                }

            }           

            }           
    });
```

Comment: You are getting only one record from recordset..

Comment: yes but i have 6 information in database but only 1 display why is that ? the for loop there is just repeating the information when 1 information is display in tableview

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try looping through your result set instead of using a single if statement. The result set pointer is only pointed to the first element and doesn't iterate through all your records

```
while(rs.next()){
     datatable.add(new StudentClass(rs.getInt("grade_No") , rs.getString("grade_Code"), 
                                rs.getString("grade_Title"), rs.getString("grade_SubjectDesc"),
                                rs.getDouble("grade_Grade"), rs.getString("grade_DaySched"),
                                rs.getString("grade_TimeSched"), rs.getString("grade_Room"), 
                                rs.getString("grade_Term"), rs.getDouble("grade_Unit"), rs.getString("grade_Faculty")));
}
```

table.setItems(datatable);

Comment: It works when the System.out.println is use but . it doesn't work in tableview. i want to put all the data to the tableview putting it to the class and so it will display in tableview

Comment: try adding the data table after the while loop so you can ensure all the data from your datasource is in your datatable list

Comment: it's still the same , the table is just getting the last data in database . i think the problem is the tableview.

Comment: could the post the code you now have with the while loop

Comment: take a look at my edit of your code should now look.

Answer (score 0):

Actually every time you enter your rs.next() loop a new "datatable" is created.

```
    ObservableList<StudentClass> datatable = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Just move the above line outside your {if (rs.next()) } loop and you are good to go.